# Updating address bar with new URL on local .html file

Tags: url, javascript, localhost

I'm having an html file somewhere placed on my computer for example
file:///C:/Users/index.html

Is it possible to manipulate that URL (using code inside that file) in a Browser which opened the file? I don't want to redirect to another homepage or something like this.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page) to update the URL with javascript for domains but only its path. I can't get anything to work for my local path and it's not really what I was searching for.

Comment: It is a mistake to expect web like behaviours while not using a web server. Why are you not using a web server? Apache is light and easy to install. I even run it on my HP mini with millions of web pages.

Comment: `FILE://` is a system file protocol which can not be rewritten the same way as a URL from a `HTTP://` protocol can. Download [XAMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) if you want pretty URLS

Comment: See on Chrome's bug tracker: [history.pushState & history.replaceState on file:/// URLs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=301210)